# Xcode, try to mark some files readonly in Xcode IDE

Tags: xcode

Is there a way to mark a file readonly in Xcode IDE?
I know I can just do it in command line, but I'm looking for a way to do in Xcode IDE so that I do not accidentally modify the readonly file/lib in my development.

What I try so far:

I'm looking around the right click menu and don't find any way to change the file attribute.

Answer (score 2):

1. Select the file in the Project Navigator.
2. Choose File > Show In Finder.
3. In the Finder, choose File > Get Info.
4. In the info window, check Locked.

[image]

Subsequently, if you try to edit the file, Xcode will put up a dialog warning you that the file is locked.